# when incoming mails insert to database, only one email detail insert to the data base

Tags: php, mysql, email, imap

with stackoverflow developers, I won my first task. I am creating incoming email insert to the database query.

this is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?PHP 

/* connect to gmail */
$hostname = '{example.org:995/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}'; 
$username = 'user';
$password = 'pass';

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to SERVER: ' . imap_last_error());


/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
if($emails) {

    /* begin output var */
    $output = '';

    /* put the newest emails on top */
    rsort($emails);

    /* for every email... */
    foreach($emails as $email_number) {

        /* get information specific to this email */
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);

        /* output the email header information */
        //$read_status  = '<div class="toggler '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
        $subject = $overview[0]->subject;
        $from    = $overview[0]->from;
        $received_date = '<span class="date">on '.$overview[0]->date.'</span>';
        //$output.= '</div>';

        /* output the email body */
        $output= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div>';
    }

    //echo $output;
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username ";
$password = "password ";
$dbname = "dbname";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

//INSERT INTO DATABASE

$sql = "INSERT INTO ads(`banner_name`, `hd_image`)VALUES('".$message."', '".$subject."') ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
} 

/* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);

?>
```

This is working well. my problem is, when I send a new mail to my email address. query will execute and insert first email details every time. not newly send email details. please help me to resolve this.

also, how can I download if email receive with an attachment?

appreciate your great help

Comment: You'll get the final item from loop (if there is multiple emails your code only insert the final one into database). Do the database operations inside the foreach loop.

Comment: Hi,
I put DB code out from the loop, but still I am receiving  my first email instead of receiving newly sent details
Thanks!

Comment: *inside the foreach loop*

Comment: Hi, It will receive all email in the inbox when I put DB query inside foreach.
how can I get only last one?

Comment: u want to insert all emails ?

Comment: no, only latest one, because every time when I receive a mail I will insert it into the database kno

Comment: it means, u need to insert last index of this array? $emails?

Comment: Yes, exactly, tell me how?

Comment: alright, can u show the array of $emails?

Comment: I have put my code above, that's only I am using? can you please check it

Comment: yes i have checked, actually u r using rsoft, which give u old record in last index...

Comment: Great! appreciate your help.
working perfectly!

Comment: also check my answer . and mark as accepted it will help to others who also facing same issue. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work @FrankLeen

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to use **[asort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)** function because **[rsort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php)** will use to reverse the order and you need the last index of array which is latest record than you will use `asort()` for getting latest record on last index.

```
asort($emails); // it will give you latest email on last index.
```

Comment: Great! appreciate your help.

Comment: @FrankLeen: glad to help u now accept the answer it will help to others... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35355581/when-incoming-mails-insert-to-database-only-one-email-detail-insert-to-the-data